Is there an Open Source tool that can issue the ABS brake bleed command over an OBDII connection?
I have a 2012 Honda Civic. I recently purchased a BlueDriver Bluetooth Pro OBDII Scan Tool for iPhone & Android, I figured this would be able to send the command to do an ABS Brake Bleeds. This would engage the pump and allow me to get the air out of the lines. But the BlueDriver unit is not bi-directional, so it's limited to diagnostics only.
Is there any open source OBDII unit that supports bi-directional communication and ideally supports issuing the command to bleed the ABS Brakes on a Honda Civic?

I know of an open source OBD scanner app for android called AndrOBD, but I doubt you can "send" commands to it.

Do you know that there even IS such an OBD command?

@kutschkem yes, there is this is one example of such tool which advertises this functionality https://www.amazon.com/FOXWELL-NT630-Plus-Bi-Directional-Calibration/dp/B07CSMJJK9
